# HELM chart for Apache degraded in argocd

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-desktop, argocd, helm3

I have tried using a HELM chart repo for Apache via ArgoCD but it shows up degraded in the console but is in sync. I am using the Kubernetes cluster on docker desktop for Mac (M1 chip). Not quite sure what the issue is.

The helm chart details are:

```
REPO URL = https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

---

```
CHART = apache:9.0.1
```

[image]
[image]

When I check the logs I see the output below:

```
macbookpro@argo-cd % argocd app logs apache
    apache 23:11:06.35 
    apache 23:11:06.37 Welcome to the Bitnami apache container
    apache 23:11:06.39 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-apache
    apache 23:11:06.41 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-apache/issues
    apache 23:11:06.43 
    apache 23:11:06.44 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache setup **
    /usr/bin/realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
    apache 23:11:06.71 INFO  ==> ** Apache setup finished! **
    
    apache 23:11:06.81 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
    [Tue Jan 25 23:11:06.943934 2022] [core:emerg] [pid 1] (95)Operation not supported: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex
    (95)Operation not supported: could not create accept mutex
    AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: That does appear like an incorrect architecture issue. https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7305

Comment: @jordanm, it seems like your comment resolves this issue since new macOS with M1 chip uses an Arm-based architecture, unlike Intel chips built on the x86 architecture. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @jordanm thank you for your answer... I found the same open issue last night so it does seem that it is the new M1 chip that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility:

That does appear like an incorrect architecture issue. Please refer to [GitHub Issue](http://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7305)